# Error With Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash

I would like to know what is the error in the below script

i get error as `: command not foundh: line 1:` , `: command not foundh: line 2:` its continuous

i have tried add `;` but now working kindly tell me what to  do ??

```
#!/bin/bash;
clear;
FILEREPO=http://192.168.1.2/cpplugin;

echo "-----------------------------------------------";
echo " Welcome to C-Panel Login Alert Installer";
echo "-----------------------------------------------";
    cd /var/cpanel/;
    mkdir perl5
    cd perl5/
    mkdir lib
    cd lib/
    wget $FILEREPO/LoginAlerthook.zip
    unzip LoginAlerthook.zip
    rm -r LoginAlerthook.zip
    cd /
    /usr/local/cpanel/bin/manage_hooks add module LoginAlert
    chmod 777 LoginAlert.pm
    echo " "
    echo " Login Alert Script Hooked With C Panel Finished"
    echo " "
```

Comment: i) remove ;  ii) check if FTP is running on 192.168.1.2

Comment: you wrote "but now working ...", did you mean but not working ...? Please edit your question to include exact copy/paste of several error messages. I can't believe the OS is printing out `command not foundh` . Good luck.

Comment: how are you executing the script?

Comment: like this sh.filename.sh

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fact that you're getting the funny output is a sure bet that your script has carriage return (CR) characters at the end of the lines, usually a symptom of using Windows editors that assume line endings should be CR/LF rather than just the standard UNIX LF (linefeed). That is causing error output like:

```
this_command_ends_hh<CR>: command not found
```

and because the CR is putting the cursor back at line start, it's overwriting some of it:

```
this_command_ends_hh<CR>
: command not found
```

making:

```
: command not foundh
```

Examine your script with `od -xcb scriptname` to check for CR (displayed as `\r`) characters, you can also pipe the script output through `od -xcb` to see the *real* output. For example is a file I created with `hello` followed by a carriage return on the one and only line:

```
0000000    6568    6c6c    0d6f    000a
          h   e   l   l   o  \r  \n
        150 145 154 154 157 015 012
0000007
```

You can see the CR (`\r`) in there.

If that *is* the problem, simply remove the CR characters such as piping it through `tr -d '\r'`.

Executing `cat hello.txt | tr -d '\r' | od -xcb` shows that you can get rid of it:

```
0000000    6568    6c6c    0a6f
          h   e   l   l   o  \n
        150 145 154 154 157 012
0000006
```

In your case, assuming your script is called `freak.bash`, you would use:

```
tr -d '\r' <freak.bash >newfreak.bash
```

and `newfreak.bash` would be the one without the offending characters.

Comment: i realy don't under stand what you are saying kindly explain me more

Comment: @Nokia808Freak, expanded a bit, hope that helps.

Comment: Sorry, @Nokia, forgot the `<` character, try again: `tr -d '\r' <loginalertinstall.sh >newloginalertinstall.sh`.

Answer (score 1):

A tool you can use to understand what is happening in the execution of this script in order to debug is the command,

```
bash -x scriptname.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

paxdiablo is almost certainly correct: you need to fix the line endings.  But you also have an errant semi-colon in the first line.  Instead of:

```
#!/bin/bash;
```

you want:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

without the trailing semi-colon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Centos 5 right now, but maybe... just maybe... bash isn't located at /bin? In FreeBSD, it's located at /usr/local/bin. In Cygwin, it's at /usr/bin. What's the output of this command:

```
which bash
```

Comment: its giving the out put as /bin/bash

Comment: What editor did you use to write your script? The only possibility that I can think of is that Linux somehow can't recognize #!/bin/bash because of a hidden character, usually a newline.

Comment: hi i have used dreamweaver in windows

Comment: Try to type the first 6 lines in Linux using ee, emacs, or vi, and see if it works... If it does, then it's definitely a newline issue.

Answer (score 0):

paxdiablo and William Pursell nicely explained what the problem is.

Now, please take the time to improve your script if you're going to distribute it.

**NOT TESTED** example:

```
#/bin/bash

ZIPFILE=http://192.168.1.2/cpplugin/LoginAlerthook.zip
CPANEL_LIBDIR=/var/cpanel/perl5/lib
MANAGE_HOOKS_CMD=/usr/local/cpanel/bin/manage_hooks

TMPFILE=`tempfile`

function exit_with_error(){
   echo "$*" >&2   # Write error messages to stderr!!
   exit 1
}

function at_exit(){
  [ -f "${TMPFILE}" ] && rm -v ${TMPFILE}
}

# Run at_exit function when script finishes
trap at_exit 0

echo "WELCOME TO ZOMBO.COM"

# Create lib directory if not exists, exit if not possible
if ! [ -d "${CPANEL_LIBDIR}" ]; then
     mkdir -p ${CPANEL_LIBDIR} || exit_with_error "Couldn't create required directory [${CPANEL_LIBDIR}]"
fi

wget ${ZIPFILE} -O ${TMPFILE} || exit_with_error "Couldn't download file"
unzip -d ${CPANEL_LIBDIR} ${TMPFILE} || exit_with_error "Couldn't unzip file"
chmod +x ${CPANEL_LIBDIR}/LoginAlert.pm || exit_with_error "Couldn't chmod file" 
$MANAGE_HOOKS_CMD add module LoginAlert

echo "End."
```

This is just a dirty example. Read the manpages to improve.

```
man bash
man tempfile
man wget
man unzip
man chmod
```